# How to get a decimal instead of a fraction in sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

I am making a chemistry project for school, I want to use sympy for solving some density and concentration problems.
`solveset` function returns the value as a fraction, for example:

```
mL = Symbol("mL")
density = Symbol("p")
mass = 115*g
volume = 100*ml
print(solveset(Eq(density, mass/volume), density))
```

The output is `{23*g/(20*mL)}` (fraction) but I want it in the decimal form (`{1.15*g/ml}`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `n()` method to evaluate the symbolic results to floats. Note that `n` is an alias of the `evalf` method. But first, you probably want to extract the result from the set of solutions:

```py
sol = solveset(Eq(density, mass/volume), density)
sol = list(sol)[0].n()
print(sol)
# 1.15*g/mL
```

Comment: `use .n(3)` to get 3 significant digits showing in answers that don't round as well.